# Can you amend super method variables before calling?

Tags: ruby

I need to monkey patch some code and i was wondering if possible to edit a single line ( specific method variable assignment ) within super before calling it ?

```rb
class Test_class

  def test
    res = "AAAAAA"
    puts res
  end

end

module TestExtensions

  def test
    # do some Ruby magic here to change res = "BBBBB" ?
    super
  end

end

class Test_class
  prepend TestExtensions
end

Test_class.new.test

---
Output is: AAAAAA
```

So in this silly example, can i edit the value of `res` and change it before calling super ? In the original class method i want to patch, I only need to change a single line, from maybe 20 lines of code in the method. Instead of copying the entire method and making a one line change i was hoping to just edit the specific line before calling super.

Update Aug 20th:

Below is the exact code i am trying to money patch.

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/remote_directory.rb#L206

Would like to change only line

```
res = Chef::Resource::CookbookFile.new(target_path, run_context)
```

to be instead

```
res = Chef::Resource::Template.new(target_path, run_context)
```

If i can not only replace this single line in the super method, maybe i can temporarily alias `Chef::Resource::CookbookFile` `=` `Chef::Resource::Template` so when calling super it returns the correct object, but i don't know if this is possible either.

Comment: Just to confirm, `res` a local variable in the method?

Comment: yes, res is just local to the `test` method. thanks.

Comment: No, that’s not possible.

Comment: If the base class is yours, it can be solved by abstracting the class more and some minor restructuring. That is typically the case if you encounter such a situation to require this. Other than that, copy-paste is unfortunately the only practical way to go without some nasty, ugly, crazy hacking that is sure to break.

Comment: If possible, define `test` in class `Test_class` as `def test(res = nil)` and inside method do: `res ||= 'AAAAAA'`. Then you will be able to call `super 'BBBBBB'`.

Comment: sadly i am not in control of the base class

Comment: Can you show the _actual_ code and explain what you're trying to achieve? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: ok apologies, i added the actual code.

Comment: @FloWoo why don't you just replace the entire method with our implementation? i.e. change the one line and copy the rest.

Comment: @stefan yup that's exactly what I am doing. I was just wondering if there was a more ninja Ruby way of only having to redefine that one line. Seems not though as it's a method local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would like to change only line
>
> ```
> res = Chef::Resource::CookbookFile.new(target_path, run_context)
> ```
>
> to be instead
>
> ```
> res = Chef::Resource::Template.new(target_path, run_context)
> ```
>
> [...] I was just wondering if there was a more ninja Ruby way [...]

Here's a **super dirty hack**. Assuming that line is the only reference to `Chef::Resource::CookbookFile`, you *could* (I don't say you should) define a constant with the same name under the receiver referencing the replacement class:

```
class Chef
  class Provider
    class RemoteDirectory

      class Chef
        class Resource
          CookbookFile = ::Chef::Resource::Template
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now `Chef::Resource::CookbookFile` within `Chef::Provider::RemoteDirectory` will resolve to the new constant which returns `::Chef::Resource::Template`, so

```
res = Chef::Resource::CookbookFile.new(target_path, run_context)
```

effectively becomes:

```
res = ::Chef::Resource::Template.new(target_path, run_context)
```